# Countdown to ON timer

Tags: timer

I am looking for a COTS countdown timer - preferably with programmable or preset, short countdown times - that will turn 110v OFF when timer is initiated, and back ON when the countdown ends.
I know I could build this with the proper relays, but I want something safe and easy, not a circuit-building project.
(I feed my fish with filter and aerator OFF but I keep forgetting to plug them back in when feeding is done.)
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, shopping questions are off-topic here. Come back if you decide you want a circuit-building project.

Comment: Connect the lights to the aerator

Comment: ebay - lotsa timer options.

Comment: You can do it with exactly one relay and one ordinary timer switch from the hardware store. This will be much safer and more reliable and off the shelf than any other way I can think of. Basically you connect your aerator to the normally closed relay terminal, and your ordinary wall switch timer energizes the relay (thus turning off your aerator) for however long the timer is set for. When the timer expires, the aerator turns back on.

Answer (score 0):

Google darkroom timers. These are designed to do what you want. You can set a time interval and the timer will keep power off (using the safelight socket) for that interval and then turn the power back on.  Used ones are readily available on Ebay and elsewhere.